# Laravel update controller with many inputs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a resource and I'm trying to set up the update controller. In my case my edit form has many inputs and I need to update the database with them but there might be columns in the database not changed by the edit form. So I have my controller like this:

```
public function update($id)
{

    $hostess = Hostess::find($id);

    $inputs=Input::all();

    foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
        $hostess->$key= $value;
    }

    if ($hostess->save())
    {
        return Redirect::route('hostesses.show', $hostess->id);
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($hostess->getErrors());
}
```

This gives me an error because I am using PUT in my view and I get

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list'
```

Because my Input::all() is getting the hidden inputs for the PUT method. I can use Input::except() for that, but is that the proper way of updating with laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually do something like this:

```
$hostess   = Hostess::find($id)

$post_data = Input::all();
// or
$post_data = Input::except('_method');

// warning untested if block below
if ($hostess->update($post_data))
{
    return Redirect::route('hostesses.show', $hostess->id);
}

return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($hostess->getErrors());
```

As short as that would update all available key and value pairs.

Do note that you have to add the `columns` to the `$fillable` property in the model to avoid the **mass assignment** warning.

Comment: Your answer is the way to go, but to make it even better add as an alternative fill(Input::all()) or new Hostess(Input::all()) as simpler, but when $fillable is set on the model.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the proper way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$inputs = Input::all();
$inputs = array_except($input, '_method');
```